# Get a range of dates given an interval and step

Tags: c#, linq

**Edit**
It looks like creating a table that holds the DateTimes by minutes to join against would make the most sense. 100 years worth of minutes is ~52M rows. Indexed by the Ticks should make the query run pretty fast. It now becomes

Thanks for the feedback everyone!

I have a class called Recurrence that looks like this:

```
public class Recurrence
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; protected set; }
    public long? RecurrenceInterval { get; protected set; }

}
```

It is an entity framework POCO class. There are two things I want to do with this class all with standard query operators. (So that the query runs entirely server side).

First I want to create a query that returns all the dates from the start date to the end date inclusive with the given recurrence interval. The iterative function is simple

```
for(i=StartDate.Ticks; i<=EndDate.Ticks; i+=RecurrenceInterval)
{
  yield return new DateTime(i);
}
```

Enumerable.Range() would be an option but there is no long version of Range. I'm thinking my only option here is Aggregate but I'm still not very strong with that function.

Finally once I have that query working, I want to return the values from there that are within a time window i.e. between a different start and end date. That is easy enough to do using SkipWhile/TakeWhile.

Here's how I could do it if DateTime.Ticks was an int

```
from recurrence in Recurrences
let range =
Enumerable
  .Range(
    (int)recurrence.StartDate.Ticks,
    recurrence.EndDate.HasValue ? (int)recurrence.EndDate.Value.Ticks : (int)end.Ticks)
  .Where(i=>i-(int)recurrence.StartDate.Ticks%(int)recurrence.RecurrenceLength.Value==0)
  .SkipWhile(d => d < start.Ticks)
  .TakeWhile(d => d <= end.Ticks)
from date in range
select new ScheduledEvent { Date = new DateTime(date) };
```

I guess what I need is an implementation of LongRange that could execute over an EF Query.

Comment: It would seem more appropriate to return dates on a daily/hourly basis rather than for every tick. How do you need to use this?

Comment: I figure that even if you could get what you want, you'll be back to ask how to improve the performance of it.  When the first step is easy and the second step is defeatingly difficult, it might mean the first step was on the wrong path.

Comment: You should consider using an existing library for Recurrence's such as [Quartz.NET](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) or [iCalendar](http://sourceforge.net/projects/dday-ical/)

Comment: @DavidB as a sql query this would be very performant already.

Comment: @Magnus the duration would vary between days, hours, even years. Sadly the client will not approve usage of Quartz wasn't aware of iCal but that'll probably be a no go as well. Also, they don't want events so much as we want to see when the events would occur within a given range of dates.

Comment: It looks like for the time being the smallest interval will be a day. So it's fine to run this code iteratively. I'd still like to see the solution though, just out of curiosity.

Comment: I think you should decrease the resolution to minutes at least. With your current implementation if the timespan is one year and the interval is set to 1, your function would return Three hundred and fifteen trillion dates.

Comment: @Magnus agreed...for the time being we don't need this much precision. We're looking at a minimum of a daily recurrence interval.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the function that yields the intersection of the Recurrence points and a specified subinterval:

```
public class Recurrence
{
    public int Id { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime StartDate { get; protected set; }
    public DateTime? EndDate { get; protected set; }
    public long? RecurrenceInterval { get; protected set; }

    // returns the set of DateTimes within [subStart, subEnd] that are
    // of the form StartDate + k*RecurrenceInterval, where k is an Integer
    public IEnumerable<DateTime> GetBetween(DateTime subStart, DateTime subEnd)
    {            
        long stride = RecurrenceInterval ?? 1;
        if (stride < 1) 
            throw new ArgumentException("Need a positive recurrence stride");

        long realStart, realEnd;

        // figure out where we really need to start
        if (StartDate >= subStart)
            realStart = StartDate.Ticks;
        else
        {
            long rem = subStart.Ticks % stride;
            if (rem == 0)
                realStart = subStart.Ticks;
            else
                // break off the incomplete stride and add a full one
                realStart = subStart.Ticks - rem + stride;
        }
        // figure out where we really need to stop
        if (EndDate <= subEnd)
            // we know EndDate has a value. Null can't be "less than" something
            realEnd = EndDate.Value.Ticks; 
        else
        {
            long rem = subEnd.Ticks % stride;
            // break off any incomplete stride
            realEnd = subEnd.Ticks - rem;
        }
        if (realEnd < realStart)
            yield break; // the intersection is empty

        // now yield all the results in the intersection of the sets
        for (long t = realStart; t <= realEnd; t += stride)
            yield return new DateTime(t);
    }

}
```

Comment: For clarification, when the answer to "Is long? A < long B" is TRUE, it means that A has a value. If it didn't, you'd get FALSE for all greater/less than/equal comparisons with B.

Comment: Combining your algorithm with Olivier's guards against edge cases.

Comment: Both very good answers. This is the more thourough algorithm though thanks!

Answer (score 3):

You could create your own date range method

```
public static class EnumerableEx
{
    public static IEnumerable<DateTime> DateRange(DateTime startDate, DateTime endDate, TimeSpan intervall)
    {
        for (DateTime d = startDate; d <= endDate; d += intervall) {
            yield return d;
        }
    }
}
```

Then query with

```
var query =
    from recurrence in Recurrences
    from date in EnumerableEx.DateRange(recurrence.StartDate,
                                        recurrence.EndDate ?? end,
                                        recurrence.RecurrenceInterval)
    select new ScheduledEvent { Date = date };
```

This assumes that `RecurrenceInterval` is declared as `TimeSpan` and `end` as `DateTime`.

---

EDIT: Would this version restrict the recurrences on the server side as you excpect?

```
var query =
    from recurrence in Recurrences
    where
        recurrence.StartDate <= end &&
        (recurrence.EndDate != null && recurrence.EndDate.Value >= start ||
         recurrence.EndDate == null)
    from date in EnumerableEx.DateRange(
        recurrence.StartDate,
        recurrence.EndDate.HasValue && recurrence.EndDate.Value < end ? recurrence.EndDate.Value : end,
        recurrence.RecurrenceInterval)
    where (date >= start)
    select new ScheduledEvent { Date = date };
```

Here the returned recurrences already take in account the `start` and the `end` date, thus not returning obsolete recurrences. `EnumerableEx.DateRange` has no effect on the first part of the query.

Comment: I added a version which should be transformed by the query provider as it uses only normal comparisons in the where clause and uses no date range enumeration here.

Comment: I see what you're saying. Once we limit the range, selecting client side should be trivial. Like I said, it works for intervals greater than a day. Most of the time the window will be for a week as well. Following YAGNI, we'll revisit the algorithm if performance becomes a problem.

Comment: A query to EF will eventually be transformed to an SQL statement. You cannot expect more of this SQL statement than containing an appropriate WHERE clause. Every supplemental logic has to be performed on the returned records (mapped to `Recurrence`). The only thing the (db) server can do, is to execute a query.

Comment: Had to break the query into two parts. Otherwise EF complains that it can't translate DateRange to a corresponding store function.